# Random shuffle of a rubik’ cube properties

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, rubiks-cube

While shuffling a Rubik’s cube, I noticed that if my shuffling had a pattern I subconsciously assumed it isn't shuffled enough so I do couple more rotations.

But, knowing that pattern can and do appear on random processes I wonder what probabilistic properties a random shuffling of a Rubik’s cube say $n$ rotations have.

- What is the average /maximal number of cubical of the same color laying on the same face, in expectation?
- How does the entropy change was $n$ increases?
- Any other interesting properties?

Comment: Since the uniform random walk on a regular graph is the uniform distribution, and the Cayley graph of the Rubik's cube group is regular, the limiting distribution of this process is as one might guess the uniform distribution, and so in particular the limit of the entropy as the number of steps goes to infinity is the logarithm of the order of the group, so $\log 43252003274489856000$, around 65 bits. By the linearity of expectation, also, the expected number of squares of a color on a side  is 1.5, but with a little careful though, all the limiting distributions can be satisfyingly found.

Comment: Is the mixing time known? Or any other convergence rate estimate of the entropy?

Comment: Not by me, but probably by someone. With a lot of computational power, you can find some exact values by iterating through the Markov Process, or you can get some slightly weaker results by simulation, but besides that I can't say anything about convergence myself.